# Hibernate exception with @MapsId, @EmbeddedId

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I've got a problem with `@MapsId` annotation and `@EmbeddedId`. When running a code in Hibernate I get:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a
>   field value by reflection setter of
>   com.test.entities.EmployeeId.serverId

But, let's start from the beginning... I have a composite primary key for entity `Employee` which consists of foreign keys to two other entities (`Server` and `Website`). In order to have a clean design I use entity relationships in Employee entity which should be reflected in the `EmployeeId` embeddable. The example is quite simple and is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Server implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String url;

    public Server() {}

    public Server(String name) {
        this.url = name;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Website implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    public Website() {}

    public Website(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeId implements Serializable {

    protected int websiteId;
    protected int serverId;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeId id;

    private String firstName;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("serverId")
    private Server server;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId("websiteId")
    private Website website;

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(String firstName, Server server, Website website) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.server = server;
        this.website = website;
    }
}
```

Now I have some simple test method written in Java SE (note this is a regular class executed from static main method - it is **not** a JUnit class):

```
private void executeTest() {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("standaloneTests");

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

    tx.begin();

    Server s = new Server("BigServer");
    em.persist(s);

    Website w = new Website("domain.com");
    em.persist(w);

    Employee e = new Employee("John", s, w);
    em.persist(e);

    tx.commit();

    em.close();
    emf.close();
}
```

As you can see, I'm not doing any fancy stuff here - just set entities in the `Employee` object and persist it. As I understand, the `@MapsId` annotation should reflect the state of the annotated entity in the `EmbeddedId`.

Now the problem is that in EclipseLink everything works smoothly and entities are properly persisted. When I change the JPA 2.0 provider to Hibernate (4.0 CR5) it throws me an **PropertyAccessException**:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by
>   reflection setter of com.test.entities.EmployeeId.serverId    at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1353)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1281)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1287)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:853)
>     at com.test.Standalone.executeTest(Standalone.java:101)     at
>   com.test.Standalone.main(Standalone.java:35) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by
>   reflection setter of com.test.entities.EmployeeId.serverId    at
>   org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectSetter.set(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:150)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.Component$ValueGenerationPlan.execute(Component.java:436)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.generate(CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.java:121)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:120)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:180)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:136)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:64)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:729)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:705)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:709)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:847)
>     ... 2 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:657)  at
>   org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectSetter.set(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:138)
>     ... 13 more

I don't know where from the NullPointerException might come from - as you can see all entity properties are set.

I don't even know **why on earth Hibernate needs a setter**, but just to be sure I've provided setters for every field (includng IDs) for `Employee`, `Website` and `Server` entities. As expected - nothing changed and Hibernate still cannot find (already present) setter.

Do you think it might be some bug or I just didn't understand some part of the JPA 2.0 contract?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Solution Here**: Got the same problem, and **got it working** now.

For it to work, the `EmployeeId` of your Employee class should be instantiated either in the constructor of Employee, or in the SessionBean before making the persistence.

Otherwise, it tries to populates the values of your embeddedid with it being null.

Not sure if this is normal or if it's a bad implementation of JPA specifications. I think the latter since the constructor for your PK is defined and hibernate should be able to call it by itself.

Comment: This solution worked for me as well. Configuring everything correctly still results in errors unless you instantiate the embedded id in the entity constructor.

Comment: Yes - that seems to be correct ... any `@MapsId` attribute needs to be explicitly instantiated and assigned when the containing `@Enitity` is instantiated. When fetching from the `EntityManger`, however, it gets correctly fetched and instantiated by the JPA implementation. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/45245021/744133

Comment: Works like a charm with _Hibernate Core 4.3.11.Final_. Thanks a lot.

Comment: worked for me with hib 5.3, spring 5.  unreal that hibernate does not have a better solution for many to many with additional join table fields.  show that even this great lib makes the mistake of being java-crazed and disregarding basic design needs of RDBMS.

Comment: It is worth noting that in this case, when using Spring Data and executing the `save` method of the repository for the newly created entity, two SQL queries will be executed: first `select` will be executed, then `update`. That is not a single `insert` query as you might expect.

Answer (score 5):

See [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-6475) issue. It simply states that

> org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException may be thrown if an Entity
>   contains the following conditions:
>
> 1. Uses @EmbeddedId
> 2. Uses @JoinTable on a collection or association property/field, which references another property/field of the entity.

As you see, the only 'workaround' suggested so far is `Do not use @EmbeddedId`, which is kind of weird.

Comment: Thanks @jFrentic. I find it definitely weird to read that 'workaround'. It's like saying that the wipers in your car are broken, so the workaround is not using them...

Comment: Yeah, it's sad, but since it was marked as *known issue* and still has `open` status, will hope that Hibernate team will do something about it in the next release. Although, I must confess that I didn't try to reproduce your issue myself. I think that I saw someone using @EmbeddedId with Hibernate and it seemed to work, but I'm not sure. If I find out more, I'll post back here.

Comment: @jFrentic - Thanks man. I've also seen a code using `@EmbeddedId`, but I think that the `@MapsId` must messed up the things here. Nevertheless, I've added a comment to the Hibernate issue and I'll wait for their answer.

Comment: This is outdated. The original issue referred to in this answer has been closed as fixed.

Answer (score 2):

its an old but might be useful for some one

try to

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private EmployeeId id;

private String firstName;

@ManyToOne
@MapsId("id")
@JoinColumn(name ="serverId")
private Server server;

@OneToOne
@MapsId("id")
@JoinColumn(name= "websiteId")
private Website website;
```

Comment: This suggestion seems even further from the correct answer than everything else. It does not appear the `@MapsId` is used correctly at all.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and fixed it by doing the following, when Hibernate attempts to set the values for Employee.id, employee.id is null, just instantiate employee.id and you'll be set.

```java
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeId id = new EmployeeId();

    private String firstName;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("serverId")
    private Server server;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId("websiteId")
    private Website website;

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(String firstName, Server server, Website website) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.server = server;
        this.website = website;
    }
}
```