# JPA/Hibernate: bidirectional OneToMany/ManyToOne relation only works unidirectional

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm currently experiencing problems with my OneToMany/ManyToOne-Mapping. The mapping looks like this:

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private AId id;

    // Other stuff...
}

@Embeddable
public class AId implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", nullable = false)
    private B b;

    // Other stuff...
}

public class B implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.b")
    private List<A> as;

    // Other stuff...
}
```

If I try to access object B by using object A everything works just fine, but the inverse direction doesn't work at all. The relationship is always null.

```
A objectA = findAById(id);
B objectB = objectA.getB(); // OK

// But... for example
objectB.getAs(); // returns null
```

I wrote a small query to get all the As for an object B using its primary key:

```
SELECT as FROM B b, IN(b.as) as WHERE b.id = :id
```

This works perfectly, I get the expected result.
I checked what is persisted in the DB, too, and it's all right. Has anybody a clue why that relationship only works in one direction?

Regards,

Alex

Comment: I doubted if mappedBy supports nested property name (I remember it did not in older version of Hibernate)

Comment: In the meantime it seems to be supported. https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/ANN-381

Comment: JPA does not allow embeddedIds to contain relationships, so this does not conform to JPA.  Why put the relationship in an embedded object anyway when you can put the relationship in the entity itself?  Using mapsid or even an ID class allows you to use just the entity and avoid having to maintain an embeddedid class within the entity.

Comment: Also check that you are setting both sides of your relationship.  A quick check would be to force a refresh on objectB so that the provider goes to the database to populate the objectBb.as relationship rather than use what might be cached.  try em.refresh(objectB);

Comment: Using MapsId annotation to have the relationships in the entity gives me a org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException Exception. Sounds a little bit like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984356/hibernate-exception-with-mapsid-embeddedid but the bug is resolved in the meantime, too :(

Comment: Following this post solves the problem with the PropertyAccessException http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?101410-Hibernate-JPA-with-MapsId but the main problem remains. The relationship is still unidirectional.

Answer (score 1):

that's because by default @onetomany has  lazy fetch. You can fix that using this
**fetch = FetchType.EAGER**

```
public class B implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.b", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<A> as;

    // Other stuff...
}
```

Comment: That would mean that lazy fetching never loads data. That's not true. Data should be loaded during first access of the relationship. Otherwise the whole concept of lazy fetching would be useless. The problem was that embeddedIds are not allowed to have relationships (like Chris posted above).