# Use of @EmbeddedId and @MapsId causes NULL inserted (NOT NULL constraint violation)

Tags: java, jpa

With using following code

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "company_id")
    private Long companyId;

    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private Long employeeNumber;
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeId id;

    private String name;

    @MapsId("name=companyId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;
}
```

When trying to persist or merge the `Employee` Entity, we can see that a `NULL` as attempted to be inserted into the company_id field.

How can I avoid a `NULL` to be inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with the wiring, when creating a new object (not fetched from the persistence context), the `company` field will remain `null`.

When Creating a new `Employee` entity, you will need to assure that you also initialize the `company` attribute:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeId id;

    private String name;

    @MapsId("name=companyId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(int id,String name,Company company) {
      this.name = name;
      this.id = new EmployeeId(id,company.id);
      this.company = company;
    }
}
```

The `Company` entity you might acquire from the persistence context using a `find`. You also can create it from scratch using it's constructor.