# JPA how to set foreign id - in Embeddable id - that is generated

Tags: jpa

My use case is: I have a Product with multi language name. To have at most one name per language a translation should be identified by locale + productId.

My problem is to get it working with a generated productId. This are the entities:
e.g. in oracle i get: "ORA-01400: cannot insert null into ."PRODUCT_NAME"."FOREIGN_ID""

Product:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(unique = true)
private String articleNumber;

/**
 * Localized name of the product.
 */
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@MapKey(name = "nameId.locale")
private Map<Locale, ProductName> names = new HashMap<>();

}
```

ProductName:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class ProductName {

@EmbeddedId
private TranslationId nameId;

private String name;

}
```

TranslationId:

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class TranslationId implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3709634245257481449L;

@Convert(converter = LocaleConverter.class)
private Locale locale;

private Long foreignId; //<-- this is null, should reference product
}
```

Is there a way to get this working without having to save the product first without the name? Without a generated id it is working of course - i just set same id for both.

I would like to re-use the translation id for other translated fields of other entities.

Comment: What is foreignId?

Comment: product's id in this case (edited the comment in code)

Comment: But there is no mapping between Product and ProductName that uses this foreign key! You would need to create a back reference from ProductName to Product to make this work.

Comment: understood - but mapping should only be in "TranslationId"?! and here is the error - the foreignid is null. I want to use this Embeddable in other translated fields (linking loclae and other entities with long id)

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984356/hibernate-exception-with-mapsid-embeddedid